# Compass not working with pyScss 1.1.5

Tags: python-2.7, sass, compass-sass

I am with Python 2.7, pyScss 1.15 and Compass 0.12.2, but Compass dosn't work, could someone give an advise how to make it work?

Comment: "Compass runs on any computer that has ruby installed." why don't you use the ruby version, when you need it anyway?

Comment: Because the project I am working on uses Python, so I need Compass for pyScss.

Comment: So what do you use for vanilla CSS? pyCSS?  Just because your project is in Python, that doesn't mean your CSS Preprocessor has to be as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need compass with pyScss. Just run "python pyScss -mscss" to watch your workingdir for changes and compile the .scss (or .sass) to .css.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone out there, but the 'compass' support advertised in pyScss is quite limited and projects written for Compass will *not* work with pyScss. I haven't been able to locate a more complete port of Compass to pyScss (or any alternatives) so the solution was to move back to Compass & Ruby.

To [cite from](http://pyscss.readthedocs.org/en/latest/syntax.html#compass-support) the pyScss docs:

> An arbitrary cross-section of Compass 0.11 is supported:
>
> - Math functions: sin, cos, tan, round, ceil, floor, pi, e
> - Images: image-url, image-width, image-height...
> - Embedded (inline) images: inline-image